# 3 Vectors and Cross Product

Tags: geometry, vectors, cross-product

Suppose there are 3 vectors  **A**, **B** and **C**.
   Consider **A**= - **C** or **C**= - **A**

Now the vector product of **B** and **A**  is **B**×**A**.

My question is Can i do this??

**B**×**A**= -(**A**×**B**)= (**-A**×**B**) = (**C**×**B**)

If no, what's the reason behind then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is valid. Scalar multiplication is compatible with the cross product: if $c$ is a scalar, then $c(A \times B) = cA \times B = A \times cB$.

Your calculation is the special case where $c = -1$.